# How to indent/autoformat HOCON in EMACS?

Tags: emacs, indentation, hocon, autoformat

Haven't found a way to indent/autoformat [HOCON](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/HOCON.md) config files. What is you way here?

Comment: You can try `kotlin-mode`, reindent, then `conf-mode`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain there isn't an Emacs major mode for HOCON. But it looks like it's similar to JavaScript, so you can make `.hocon` load as JavaScript by adding this to your `.emacs`:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.hocon\\'" . javascript-mode))
```

Comment: Unfortunately it looks similar to JS, but it isn't similar enough :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's quite similar to the syntax of [HCL](https://github.com/hashicorp/hcl). You might be interested in using [emacs-hcl-mode](https://github.com/purcell/emacs-hcl-mode) for editing HOCON files.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).